# Include OpenCV library dll's with CMake

Tags: c++, dll, opencv, cmake, mingw

I am trying to write a C++ application using the OpenCV libraries.  As per the recommendation from the OpenCV maintainers, I am using CMake to generate the Makefile.  My platform is Windows 7 (64 bit).  My compiler is MinGW (so I am using the 'mingw32-make' tool to build the application).

Right now I am trying to make sure my setup is correct so I can move forward with the code.  I have verified that the OpenCV libraries have been built correctly.  I then tried to verify that I could use CMake to include the OpenCV libraries in my build.  I am using the following sample code from an OpenCV tutorial:

DisplayImage.cpp

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Mat image;
    image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

    if (argc != 2 || !image.data)
    {
        printf( "No image data \n" );
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "Display Image", image );

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.8 )

project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

I used cmake-gui to generate the Makefile, then used mingw32-make to build the application.  Everything works fine and the program compiles with no errors.  However, when I try to run it, Windows stops and complains that it needs libopencv_core231.dll.  I have checked and this dll is in my (OpenCV Build location)/bin directory.  How can I get CMake/MinGW to include this when compiling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

copy opencv dlls into your executable folder.

```
MACRO (COPY_DLL trgt libname)
        ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND (
        TARGET ${trgt}
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
        ARGS -E copy "${OPENCVDIR/bin}/${libname}.dll" ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    )
ENDMACRO (COPY_DLL)
```

Comment: Isn't CMake supposed to include the directories with the dll's for me so I don't have to copy them into every executable folder?

Comment: It is not CMakes's problem. The operating system is searching for the required dll's.

Comment: Yes, but isn't CMake supposed to tell the executable where it can find them?

Comment: No. It does tell where the libs and header files are. Execution environment is not a concern of CMake.

Comment: Application loader will load the executable and the required dll's. You can not specify in a exe file that it should load the dll's from a specified folder. The loader will search for dll's in system folder, in PATH, current working directory...

Comment: I would think there would be some way to tell g++ that when it compiles the program, the executable should look for the dll's in a certain folder.  (I assume that dll's do not always have to reside in the same folder as an executable)  It seems like CMake would be doing this, since it is writing the Makefile.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your latest post.  So I need to add the bin directory to my PATH?

Comment: more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: I agree with astay. CMake should be capable of telling Visual Studio to add certain paths (e.g. containing required dlls) to the PATH environment variable. Currently, it is a pain in the *** to add these paths manually.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I looked for something working using visual Studio (which supports multiple configurations in the build tree), the command would be slightly modified.
the command works in parallel of `find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )`

**first**: get output dll (build as the unique opencv_world lib)

```
get_target_property(__dll_dbg opencv_world IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG)
get_target_property(__dll_release opencv_world  IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE)
```

**Then** you could add a command:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${TARGET_NAME} POST_BUILD        # Adds a post-build event the TARGET
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different           # which executes "cmake - E copy_if_different..."
    "$<$<CONFIG:debug>:${__dll_dbg}>$<$<CONFIG:release>:${__dll_release}>"      # <--this is in-file
    $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${TARGET_NAME}>                        # <--this is out-file path
        # another dll copy if needed here
    COMMENT "    [1718_34_ATK] copy dlls realsense2 and opencv_world")
```

Comment: Where can this property value __dll_dbg be found in OpenCV building process?

Answer (score 2):

I use [`configure_file(...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) which copies specified `.dll` files when they change (rarely) for the right compiler using `${_OpenCV_LIB_PATH}`.

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
configure_file("${_OpenCV_LIB_PATH}/opencv_world451d.dll" ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} COPYONLY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with:

`opencv_world470.dll` is already in my path while I am developing so when launching a debugger or the app locally, I am ok.

Now for the installation, cpack using WIX or NSIS, getting the property from the target `opencv_world` to get to know where is the dll on my device such that I can packaging it later  -- along with the LICENSE file of opencv of course...

```
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

# it took me forever to figure this one out
get_target_property(opencv_world_dll_source_filepath opencv_world IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE)
install(FILES ${opencv_world_dll_source_filepath} DESTINATION bin)
```